# CodeIgniter; difference between libraries and drivers

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, difference

CodeIgniter [libraries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) are expected to be stored under the `application/libraries` directory so as to be accessible when initialized.

[Drivers](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/drivers.html#using-codeigniter-drivers) on the other hand are said to be a special *type of Library* and are found in the `system/libraries/` directory, in their own sub-directory.

In their [creation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_drivers.html#driver-directory-and-file-structure) (of drivers), they are not depicted to be stored under the `system/libraries/` directory as expected but `/application/libraries/`, named just as *libraries*.

What then is/are the difference(s) between CodeIgniter [libraries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html) and [drivers](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/drivers.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/drivers.html)

> Drivers are a special type of Library that has a parent class and any number of potential child classes.

Child classes have access to the parent class, but not their siblings.

They are useful when you want to create an [abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer).

The class `CI_Cache`  (found in `/system/libraries/Cache/Cache.php`) is probably the easiest to get your head around; it "abstracts" various cache systems (apc, memcached, redis, etc.) so that the different cache systems can be used with the same set of functions.

Other examples in the framework that use abstraction (but not the `CI_Driver_Library`) are `CI_session` and the database classes.

These two tutorials might give you some ideas and additional background:

1. [Codeigniter Drivers Tutorial](http://www.kevinphillips.co.nz/news/codeigniter-drivers-tutorial/)
2. [How to Create Custom Drivers in CodeIgniter](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-drivers-in-codeigniter--cms-29339)

All developer created classes (controllers, models, drivers, etc.) should be placed in the appropriate sub-directory of the `/application` folder.

You should never place developer created files in the `/system` folder or its sub-folders.

Drivers are loaded using `$this->load->driver('lib_name');`